# Writing JQuery If Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, addclass

I am trying to write a JQuery If Statement.. What I am trying to achieve is basically to highlight the appropriate link (a) when the certain div (infotab) is clicked. They are all hidden as you can see, but when clicked, become visible in a nice fade. I want to highlight the item that was clicked. (Change the background color to whatever I want, such as red in the code below.)

The code I have below works, but incorrectly. It highlights all of the a's in that div. I just want the one highlighted that was clicked. Thanks for your help you guys are great.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#infotab_two_s, #infotab_three_s, #infotab_four_s, #infotab_five_s').hide();
});

$('.subnav_holster li').click(function () {
    var Vinfotab = this.id + '_s';
    $('.infotab:visible').fadeOut('fast', function () {
        $('#' + Vinfotab).fadeIn('fast');
        var Vinfotab_selected = 'Vinfotab:visible';
        $("subnav_holster li a").css({
            "color": "red"
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cache `this` and then highlight it:

```
$('.subnav_holster li').click(function () {
    var Vinfotab = this.id + '_s',
        $this = $(this);
    $('.infotab:visible').fadeOut('fast', function () {
        $('#' + Vinfotab).fadeIn('fast');
        var Vinfotab_selected = 'Vinfotab:visible';
        $('.subnav_holster li a').css({
            "background-color": "white" // reset all to default color
        });
        $this.find('a').css({
            "background-color": "red"   // set highlight to this element only
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: why cache this? Also is it possible to remove the effect if another div is selected?

Comment: That's what the line with `// reset all to default color` is for

Comment: I mean if another tab is clicked, the original tab will still be red. I want it to go back to white. Do you get it?

Comment: I updated my answer with the color you specified... do you get it?

Answer (score 2):

Grab the `li` that was clicked and access that element's `a`:

```
$('.subnav_holster li').click(function () {
    var Vinfotab = this.id + '_s';
    var clicked = $(this);
    $('.infotab:visible').fadeOut('fast', function () {
        $('#' + Vinfotab).fadeIn('fast');
        var Vinfotab_selected = 'Vinfotab:visible';
        clicked.find('a').css({
            "color": "red"
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: wonderful!!!! Now how could I change i remove the color though if another li is clicked?

Comment: @Josh: After the `clicked.find('a')` bit, do `clicked.siblings().find('a').css({ "color": "white" });`. This turns the other `li a` elements back to white.

Comment: doesn't seem to work.. If another li is clicked, I don't want the original to be red. I want the current button to be the color, not allow all of them to be red. Do you get it

Comment: @Josh: Oh, right. The `clicked.find()` and `clicked.siblings()` bits need to be moved out of the fade function for it to work properly.